# Cannot Find os-tempdir in cordova command

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, html-framework-7

Hi Im getting the error below when installing a cordova plugin can someone help?

```
$ cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-inappbrowser module.js:474
throw err;
^

Error: Cannot find module 'os-tmpdir'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:472:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:420:25)
at Module.require (module.js:500:17)
at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\osenv\osenv.js:4:16)
at Module._compile (module.js:573:32)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:582:10)
at Module.load (module.js:490:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:449:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:441:3)
```

Comment: I just had the same error when trying to build. Does build work for you?

Comment: build works for me but I cant try the inaapbrowser and now I cant download other plugins T_T